# What does MKS state for in VMWare MKS?

Tags: vmware

What is MKS in context of Horizon Client?
Using Horizon Client I experienced a crash after which there was a log file generated with a name `vmware-mks-7788`. I don't get which part `mks` relates to.

Comment: Mouse, keyboard, screen (for vmware clients in general, not just Horizon).

Comment: @dxiv, why mouse, keyboard, and screen?

Comment: I copied a couple of VMWare references below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MKS" is used as an abbreviation for "*mouse, keyboard, screen*" in the context of VMWare clients, for example [Troubleshooting virtual machine console and MKS issues in the vSphere Client](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/749640).

For Horizon in particular, from the VMWare [Horizon Client for Windows Logs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-6/6.2/com.vmware.horizon-client-agent.security.doc/GUID-3127B73A-B6DB-44F3-856B-5FDB8E5C21FD.html) page:

> ```
> Type of logs:    Remote MKS (mouse-keyboard-screen) logs
>                  From the vmware-remotemks.exe process
>
> Directory path:  C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\
>                  vmware-username ViewMP-Client-XXXXXX.log
>
> File Name:       vmware-mks-XXXXXX.log
>                  vmware-rdeSvc-XXXXXX.log
> ```